# What's the difference of hashCode() and equals()?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I was thinking and this question came to my mind what is the relationship between `hashCode()` and `equals()`? Also, what is the significance of these methods? And, what are the requirements for implementing them?

Comment: All of those questions can be answered by reading their corresponding Javadoc.

Comment: @JigarJoshi I think that is a totally different question compared to mine. If you really look at it.

Comment: That question's answers answer everything you just asked.

Comment: if you check the answer, it will answer your question, question title could be differnet

Comment: Sorry I did not see the answer, Thanks I guess for directing me to the answer that I was looking for.